# TouchableNativeFeedback Ripple over the entire screen?

Tags: react-native

I am currently using `TouchableNativeFeedback` to provide ripples when pressing buttons in React Native on Android.

It looks like this:

```
  <TouchableNativeFeedback
    background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('rgba(3, 155, 229, 0.3)')}
    onPress={() => {onClick(text)}}
    delayPressIn={0}
  >
      ....
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

I know I can make the ripple render outside the view bounds like this:

```
<TouchableNativeFeedback
    background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('gray', true)}
>
    ...
</TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

However, the ripples fade out over a small radius (although they do go out of the view bounds). Is there any way to make a huge ripple the size of the entire screen?

I have a button that clears an input (kinda like a clear button on a calculator), and I want a big red ripple over the entire screen when the user hits that clear button.

---

```
react-native: 0.28.0
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react: 15.1.0
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to control the ripple radius? I want to make my touch target 48x48 per material guidelines, but the ripple should stop at 40x40.

Comment: @Noitidart same here

Answer (score 0):

It seems [`TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablenativefeedback#ripple) takes second and third argument which are `borderless` and `rippleRadius`. Those were the exactly what we were looking for.

Following example makes a big ripple:

```html
<TouchableNativeFeedback
  onPress={onPress}
  background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('', true, 300)}>
```